# how to retrieve records from mysql which are inserted in 30mins interval?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a requirement of counting the no. of records inserted into a table for every half an hour.say from 11 to 11 30 if there 5 records and 11 30 to 12 if there are 4 records how to find the no. of records

Comment: Depends on how your data looks like

Comment: Clearly there is not enough info here to be helpful. But maybe if there is a column in your table that defines the time that the data was inserted you can select data through a stored procedure that is between two times..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need the datetime each row was inserted; it's easiest if that is a column in the table. (We'll assume here that the column is named `inserted_dt`.)

All that we really need is an expression that operates on `inserted_dt` to return a single value for every value within a given half hour.

If we needed "hour" intervals, and not "half-hour" intervals, it would be very easy:

```
    DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Let's define the first "half-hour" ranges as minutes >= '00' AND minutes < '30'

To get the "minutes" out of the `inserted_dt` column, we could use either of

```
    EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM t.inserted_dt)

    DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%i')
```

We can use a conditional test to determine whether the minutes value is less than 30, or flip it around and test for greater than or equal to thirty:

```
    DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%i')+0 >= 30
```

We can put that back together with the "year-month-day-hour", by adding an interval of either 0 or 30 minutes,

```
    DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') 
      + INTERVAL 30*(DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%i')+0>=30) MINUTE
```

(There are lots of expressions we could use to do something similar; this one is just one of the shortest we can use to return a DATETIME datatype

Now, we just add the expression to the SELECT list of our query, we get a value that identifies the "halfhour".

To get a "count" for each half hour range, that's just a simple `COUNT()` aggregate and a `GROUP BY`. The "trick" is that we use the new "halfhour" expression in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
         + INTERVAL 30*(DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%i')+0>=30) MINUTE AS halfhour
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY halfhour
```

Obviously, add a WHERE clause if you only want to return results for a specified datetime range,

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
         + INTERVAL 30*(DATE_FORMAT(t.inserted_dt,'%i')+0>=30) MINUTE AS halfhour
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.inserted_dt >= '2014-08-12'
   AND t.inserted_dt <  '2014-08-12' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
 GROUP BY halfhour
```